# Trying to understand the sum of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm having a hard time with the functions defined by transfinite induction, in particular I have the sum of two ordinals defined as follows:
\begin{align}\alpha+0&=\alpha \\ 
\alpha+s(\beta)&=s(\alpha+\beta)\\ 
\alpha+\beta&=\sup_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma)\quad \mbox{(if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal)} \end{align}

I've noticed that if $\alpha<\omega$ then $\alpha + \omega =\omega$ and it seems to me that if I replace $\omega$ by any other countable limit ordinal that assertion still holds, is this right? And, can it be generalized to any limit ordinal?

I feel I'm still not able to grasp the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the case that if $\alpha < \omega$, then $\alpha + \omega = \omega$, and similarly for other countable limit ordinals $\beta$ that $\alpha + \beta = \beta$.

A way of thinking of this that may be more intuitive for you than the definition that you give is that the ordinal sum $\alpha + \beta$ is the order type that you get by ``gluing a copy of $\beta$ after $\alpha$''.

Formally, if we define the set
$$
S_{\alpha, \beta} = \{(0, i) \mid i < \alpha\} \cup \{(1, j) \mid j < \beta\},
$$

and order $S_{\alpha, \beta}$ lexicographically, then $\alpha + \beta$ is exactly the order type of $S_{\alpha, \beta}$, which we can show by a transfinite induction on $\beta$:

If $\beta = 0$, then $S_{\alpha, \beta} = \{(0, i) \mid i < \alpha\}$, which has order type $\alpha$, as shown by the map $(0, i) \mapsto i$.

If $\beta = s(\gamma)$, then $S_{\alpha, \beta} = S_{\alpha, \gamma} \cup \{(1, \gamma)\}$, which has order type equal to ${\rm ot}(S_{\alpha, \gamma}) + 1$, which, by induction, is precisely $\alpha + \gamma + 1 = s(\alpha + \gamma)$.

If $\beta$ is limit, then we note that $S_{\alpha, \beta} = \bigcup\limits_{\gamma < \beta} S_{\alpha, \gamma}$, and since the $S_{\alpha, \gamma}$ are nested and increasing, we have easily that ${\rm ot}(S_{\alpha, \beta}) > {\rm ot}(S_{\alpha, \gamma})$ for all $\gamma < \beta$.

It therefore remains to show that this is the least upper bound. But if $\delta < {\rm ot}(S_{\alpha, \beta})$, then there is some $\gamma$ such that $\delta < {\rm ot}(S_{\alpha, \gamma})$, and so we have that ${\rm ot}(S_{\alpha, \beta}) = \alpha + \beta$.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:** There's an amusing generalization of all this at the bottom.

An *ordinal* determines an *ordering*. The ordering corresponding to the sum of two ordinals is "first an ordering like this one, followed by an ordering like that one".

So for example the ordinal $3$ corresponds to three things in a row: $xxx$ .

And $\omega$ corresponds to an infinite sequence: $xxxxxx\dots$ .

If you take three things in a row and follow them  by an infinite sequence you get an infinite sequence: $$xxx,xxx\dots = xxx\dots$$So $3+\omega=\omega$.

If $n<\omega$ then $n+\alpha=\alpha$ for any infinite ordinal $\alpha$, nothing to do with whether it's a limit ordinal. Because $\alpha$ starts with an infinite sequence, then perhaps has more added on - that sequence eats the $n$, as in the example $3+\omega=\omega$ above.

---

**Amusing Generalization.** For $n<\omega$ define $\alpha n=\alpha+\dots+\alpha$. Define $\alpha\omega=\bigcup_{n<\omega}\alpha n.$

**Theorem** Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals. We have $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ if and only if $\alpha+\beta$ is *obviously* equal to $\beta$.

Or a little more explicitly,

**Theorem** Given two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ if and only if $\beta\ge\alpha\omega$.

Proof: If $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ then $\alpha n+\beta=\beta$, and hence $\beta\ge\alpha n$, for every $n<\omega$. Hence $\beta\ge\alpha\omega$.

Otoh if $\beta\ge\alpha\omega$ then $\beta=\alpha\omega+\gamma$, hence $\alpha+\beta=\beta$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it in the last paragraph somehow.

Answer (score 7):

The intuition is actually quite a bit simpler than the recursive definition. For any linear orders $\langle A,\le_A\rangle$ and $\langle B,\le_B\rangle$, not necessarily well orders, we can define a linear order that is their sum: the underlying set is $(\{0\}\times A)\cup(\{1\}\times B)$, and the order $\le$ is lexicographic: $\langle i,x\rangle\le\langle j,y\rangle$ iff either $i<j$, or $i=j=0$ and $x\le_A y$, or $i=j=1$ and $x\le_B y$. Essentially we’re just putting $B$ with its given linear order after $A$ with its linear order:

$$\overset{A}\longrightarrow\overset{B}\Longrightarrow\;.$$

The bit with the $0$ and $1$ is a technical detail to ensure that we’re working with disjoint sets; it’s unnecessary if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

In the case of ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we can form a sum in just this fashion: the underlying set is $(\{0\}\times\alpha)\cup(\{1\}\times\beta)$, and we have $\langle i,\xi\rangle\le\langle j,\eta\rangle$ iff $i<j$, or $i=j$ and $\xi\le \eta$. It’s not at all hard to check that this order $\le$ is a well-order, so it is order-isomorphic to a unique ordinal $\gamma$, and we write $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$. Intuitively, $\gamma$ is the ordinal whose order type is obtained by sticking a copy of $\beta$ after a copy of $\alpha$.

It might be worthwhile to try proving to yourself that this more intuitive approach yields the same result as the recursive definition.

When $\alpha$ is finite and $\beta$ is not, $\alpha$ together with the first $\omega$ elements of $\beta$ still form just one copy of $\omega$, so — as you said — in this case $\alpha+\beta=\beta$. This can be generalized, but it takes a bit of care. Let $\alpha_0=\alpha$. Given $\alpha_n$ for some $n\in\omega$, let $\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_n+\alpha$. Finally, let $\eta=\sup_n\alpha_n$. (In fact $\eta=\alpha\cdot\omega$, which the multiplication is ordinal multiplication.) Then $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ whenever $\beta\ge\eta$, because one more $\alpha$ just gets absorbed into the initial $\eta$ part of $\beta$.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can understand better if you compare it with a direct definition : the sum of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the unique ordinal isomorphic to the well-ordered set $\alpha \coprod \beta$ given the order the extends that of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and such that every element of $\alpha$ is strictly inferior to any element of $\beta$ (so it's like you put a copy of $\alpha$ next to a copy of $\beta$).